# Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() XAMPP

Tags: php, openssl

I run XAMPP an I have this PHP Code:

```
$salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));
$hash = crypt($_POST['password'], "$2a$12$".$salt);
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

PHP version: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

I have tried to recompile PHP with openssl;

[image: cmd recompile]

But thats not working to (see error), how to fix it?

Comment: Try `.\configure`, and not `.configure`.